# Calling original method in overloading

Tags: java

Is it a good practice to overload method in Java, calling this original method inside a new one but passing some default values as parameters for original method?

Comment: yes it's a telescopic methods/constructors. builders are alternatives for ones

Comment: There is a dedicated **item** in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Comment: This is a normal practice.

Comment: I'd say that as long as it makes sense that two methods have the same name (they do the "same thing"), then sure, overloading is normal.  Be on the look-out however for methods that could have different names, because sometimes overloaded names can be confusing to read if there is a subtle difference in operation based only on the number or order of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters noted, this is a standard practice. Typically, it is used to allow simplified signatures in order to provide default values. Like any other, pattern, some thought should be taken to avoid abusing it.